# hello I am a beginner Django developer I am facing issue in Payment integration with stripe

Tags: python, django, rest, stripe-payments

I'm creating an ecommerce web app in django everything is working fine without payment integration (stripe)
Now when i integrated stripe the only thing I'm facing is that i cannot pass the total amount in cart to my charge.py function which will simply charge the card the amount in cart

views.py

```
from locale import currency
from django.urls import reverse
import stripe
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import  JsonResponse
from .models import *
import json
from .utils import cookieCart,cartData,guestOrder

stripe.api_key = "sk_test_51LGVvZLOhjoxBBs0eMasEkak6VRuemLVz7KEHubNhiFwiGwMPO20RNLiDXJEkQwiCU7eGIuBawvSjpSKX8ImI7S600soefS68W"

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    data=cartData(request)
    
    cartItems=data['cartItems']

    products = Product.objects.all()[:3]
    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems}

    return render(request, 'Home.html',context)
def aboutUs(request):

    return render(request, 'aboutUs.html')

def contactUs(request):

    return render(request, 'contactUs.html')

def terms(request):

    return render(request, 'Terms.html')

def store(request):
    data=cartData(request)
    
    cartItems=data['cartItems']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems}

    return render(request, 'store.html', context)

def productDetails(request,id):

    data=cartData(request)
    
    cartItems=data['cartItems']

    products = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'products': products, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    print(products)
    
    return render(request, 'productDetails.html', context)




def cart(request):
    data=cartData(request)
    
    cartItems=data['cartItems']
    order=data['order']
    items=data['items']

    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'cart.html', context)


def checkout(request):
    data=cartData(request)
    
    cartItems=data['cartItems']
    order=data['order']
    items=data['items']
    print(order.get_cart_total)

    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)


def update_item(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action: ', action)
    print('productId: ', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)
    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)
    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('item was added', safe=False)


def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
       


    else:
        customer,order = guestOrder(request,data)
        
    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id

    if total == order.get_cart_total:
            order.complete = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
                customer=customer,
                order=order,
                address=data['shipping']['address'],
                city=data['shipping']['city'],
                state=data['shipping']['state'],
                zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
            )

    return JsonResponse('Payment submitted..', safe=False)

# payment integration
def charge(request):
    data=cartData(request)
    
    cartItems=data['cartItems']
    order=data['order']
    items=data['items']
    print(order.get_cart_total)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Data:', request.POST,'amount: ',order.get_cart_total)

        customer=stripe.Customer.create(
            email=request.POST['email'],
            name=request.POST['nickname'],
            source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
            )
        charges=stripe.Charge.create(
            customer=customer,
            amount=50000000,
            currency='pkr',
            description='cardPayment'
        )



    return redirect(reverse('success', args=[amount]))

def payment(request):

    return render(request, 'payment.html')

def successMsg(request, args):
    amount = args
    return render(request, 'success.html', {'amount':amount})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price=models.FloatField()
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    image1=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    image2=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    image3=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    image4=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    @property
    def imageURL1(self):
        try:
            url=self.image1.url
        except:
            url=''
        return url
    @property
    def imageURL2(self):
        try:
            url=self.image2.url
        except:
            url=''
        return url
    @property
    def imageURL3(self):
        try:
            url=self.image3.url
        except:
            url=''
        return url
    @property
    def imageURL4(self):
        try:
            url=self.image4.url
        except:
            url=''
        return url

class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping=False
        orderitems=self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in orderitems:
            if i.product.digital==False:
                shipping=True
        return shipping
    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems=self.orderitem_set.all()
        total=sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total
    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems=self.orderitem_set.all()
        total=sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total=self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total


class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    zipcode=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home,name='home'),
    path('store/', views.store,name='store'),
    path('cart/', views.cart,name='cart'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout,name='checkout'),
    path('about-us/', views.aboutUs,name='about_us'),
    path('contact-us/', views.contactUs,name='contact_us'),
    path('terms/', views.terms,name='terms'),
    path('update_item/', views.update_item,name='update_item'),
    path('product/<int:id>/', views.productDetails,name='productDetails'),
    path('process_order/', views.processOrder,name='process_order'),
    path('charge/', views.charge, name="charge"),
    path('success/<str:args>/', views.successMsg, name="success"),
    path('payment/', views.payment, name="payment"),
]
```

cart.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="box-element">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'store' %}">&#8592; Continue Shopping</a>


      <br>
      <br>

      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h5>items : <strong>{{order.get_cart_items}}</strong></h5>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h5>Total : <strong>${{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2 }}</strong></h5>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="blue-button">
            <a style="float:right ;margin: 5px;" class="btn" href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
          </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="box-element">
      <div class="cart-row">
        <div style="flex:2 ;"></div>
        <div style="flex:2 ;"><strong>item</strong> </div>
        <div style="flex:1 ;"><strong>Price</strong></div>
        <div style="flex:1 ;"><strong>Quantity</strong></div>
        <div style="flex:1 ;"><strong>Total</strong></div>

      </div>
      {% for item in items %}
      <div class="cart-row">
        <div style="flex:2 ;"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL1}}" alt=""></div>
        <div style="flex:2 ;">{{item.product.name}} </div>
        <div style="flex:1 ;">{{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</div>
        <div style="flex:1 ;">
          <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
          <div class="quantity">
            <img data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="add" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'images/arrow-up.png' %}" alt="">
            <img data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="remove" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'images/arrow-down.png' %}" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex:1 ;">${{item.get_total|floatformat:2}}</div>

      </div>

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You state "i cannot pass the total amount in cart to my charge".  I assume this is the charge function in your `views.py` file.  That looks correct as far as creating a charge per https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=pythonhttps://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=python.  Could you elaborate on what error you are receiving?  Also you may want to check that the currency specified is supported in your country.  Try looking here: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies

Comment: does you order total display properly? (sum of quantities)

Comment: im getting my total amount in cart which is the sum of all the items i have added in cart and also in checkout page i just want to pass the total amount in charge function

Comment: by this code im gettiing amount zero in charge function

Comment: Yes stripe is also working fine with pkr if I give a static value it is working fine but when I pass my models.py property of get_cart_total I return amount zero in the charge function but the real value in the checkout function in views.py  i hope this gives you much explanation  thank you